# Copying `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face`

Tags: fonts, emacs

Because I use bold font by default, I want to have normal weight for comments.  I start with setting the weight for `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face` to normal, then copying to `font-lock-comment-face`.

Here is the function I have constructed.  Does it make sense approaching the task in this way?

```
(defun richkov-annotation-font-weight ()
  "Use normal weight typeface for comments."
  (set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-delimiter-face nil :weight 'normal)
  (copy-face 'font-lock-comment-delimiter-face 'font-lock-comment-face) )
```

Comment: `copy-face old-face new-name &optional frame new-frame`. Should this not copy `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face` to `font-lock-comment-face`?

Comment: How doesit work exactly?

Comment: This means that copy-face goes first?

Comment: So this should work.  Is there anything else I have to add?  I just add customisation to `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face`, and they are then copied over to `font-lock-comment-face`.

Comment: Seems as if font-lock-comment-delimiter-face inherits from font-lock-comment-face. Could mean that copying font-lock-comment-delimiter-face is not necessary?